# JSF Trinidad SelectBooleanCheckbox with out Label

Tags: java, html, jsf, trinidad

Using Trinidad selectBooleanCheckbox Component as following:

```
<tr:selectBooleanCheckbox text="FIRST" id="firstType" value="#{bean.type}"/>
```

The render html is :

```
<tr>
<td>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary=""
        style="padding: 0px" class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox"
        id="idtable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap="" class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox_label"><span
                    style="display: none;" id="firstType::icon"><a
                        class="AFErrorIconStyle" title="Error"
                        name="_msgAnc_firstType">X</a>
                </span>
                </td>

<td valign="top" nowrap="" class="AFContentCell">
                    <span id="firstType__xc_c"
                    class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox_content"><input
                        type="checkbox" checked="" value="t" name="first"
                        id="firstType"><label for="firstType">FIRST</label>
                </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

<tr>
                <td></td>

                <td class="AFComponentMessageCell">
                    <span style="margin-left: 21px; padding: 0px"
                    class="OraInlineErrorText" id="first::msg"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

My Question is :

I'm not using the label , instead I'm using text property(since I want to render the checkbox first and then the text- when I'm using the label the label shows before the checkbox)

So what I want is the html that is render will not render the  section of the label at all
because it take some place that I can't remove..

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem

I just added the attribute `simple="true"` which removed the message and label from the html
according the [Trinidad API for `selectBooleanCheckbox`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_selectBooleanCheckbox.html).

the new Code:

```
<tr:selectBooleanCheckbox text="FIRST" id="firstType" value="#{bean.type}" simple="true"/>
```